# unity 2018 pixel perfect Camera , can i zoom in and out?

Tags: unity-game-engine, pixel-perfect

Two questions the first how to zoom in and zoom out ? and why i have that red line in some resolutions is it a bug or a problem (i tried reimporting the package and recreate the project but nothing new) ? [image]

Answer (score 2):

It's about resolution and aspect ratio.

I see you are using an asset for this "Pixel Perfect Camera". If you want to zoom in and out you need to make sure you are staying in line with the original supported resolutions (and the aspect ratio).

On your camera settings the "Reference Resolution" is 320x180, on the error it says you're in "485x279", so it seems your project is in 16:9 (aspect ratio).

20*16 and 20*9 = 320x180. Keep your resolution in line with your aspect ratio. Simply put, you need a multiple of **16** for width and of **9** for height.

Comment: the asset is an unity beta version package , yes there something related to the resolution but i didn't understood it clearly , i thought this pixel perfect package will be enough to make game playable in different devices i tried everything in the settings but nothing new so i want to see if it's a bug or a pb from me or it's not something to worry about .

Comment: Read my answer again, I edited it so you could understand better =)

Comment: yeah i discoverd just a few moments ago that i did a mistake when i added the 800x480 resolution in the game view for the first time ; i make it as an aspect ratio " : " and not a fixed resolution " x " , thank you.